# jQuery mouseup event on click and drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mousedown, mouseup

I'm trying to show a `div` when the user click a box. I tried to use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hold").mousedown(function(){
    $(".box").css("height","200px");
  });
  $(".hold").mouseup(function(){
    $(".box").css("height","0px");
  });
});
```

But the second part of the code, the `mouseup` event doesn't trigger the callback when I click and drag.

How to make it work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>click and hold project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="hold"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>

    <script src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your issue that, when you click and drag the box remains even though you'd like it hidden? It's because you're not "mouseupping" in `.box`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@wahwahwah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061096/jquery-click-and-drag/37061996#comment61669754_37061096) pointed it out, the issue is that when you press the mouse key on the `.hold` element and then move the mouse somewhere else and leave the key, the given handler on `mouseup` would NOT be called because it is set on the `.hold` element.

Technically, the target of the event would be different in that case, hence it won't match the `.hold` element and eventually the callback functions of `mouseup` event won't be triggered.

A workaround to this could be to add a pointer to the clicked element at the beginning and then add an event listener on the document element and check whether the `event.target` is the same as the clicked element.

If they are not the same, we will trigger the `.hold` element's event manually, as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var mouseTarget;

  $(".hold").on('mousedown', function(){
    $(".box").css("height", "200px");
    mouseTarget = this;
  })
  .on('mouseup', function(){
    $('.box').css("height", "0px");
  });

  $(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    if (e.target !== mouseTarget) {
      $(mouseTarget).trigger(e.type);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hold{
  background-color: #000;
  width: 20%;
  height: 10px;
}
.box{
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hold"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

It is worth mentioning that the callback function which is set on the `document` will be triggered in the bubble phase.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hold").mousedown(function(){
    $(".box").css("height","200px");
  })
  .mouseup(function(){
    $(".box").css("height","0px");
  });
});
```

jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/w47anse9/

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as it is. Are you trying to drag or expand the box? I only added styles to it.

```
.hold {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Here is fiddle with your code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j30872oa/)